# What IP address ranges are used for local addresses on cellular internet networks?

Tags: router, wireless, ipv4

I have an application that requires users who share a 3G or 4G network access point (same public IP address) to communicate directly through their local IP addresses rather than trying to traverse their global IP addresses, but the local network addresses on my T-mobile 3G and 4G network are not like normal local IP addresses on most routers - they never start with `192`, `172`, or `10`. Instead, they start with other numbers - for example, my phone now says that my private IP address is `21.48.25.107`. How do you tell if an IP address is a local address when the IP address originates from a cellular network?

**Clarification:**

I am implementing a peer to peer NAT traversal solution for cellular applications. I avoid using the public IP address when the devices share a common public IP address because most routers do not support hairpin translation.

> Hairpin is a behavior where a NAT device forwards packets from a host
>   in an internal network (lets call it host A) back to some other host
>   (host B) in the same internal network when it detects that the
>   (public IP address) destination of the packet is actually a mapped IP
>   address that was created for the internal host (host B). This is a
>   desirable behavior of a NAT, but, unfortunately, not all NAT devices
>   support this. Lacking this behavior, two (internal) hosts behind the
>   same NAT will not be able to communicate with each other if they
>   exchange their public addresses.

That is why they must exchange and use their local IP addresses if they share a public IP address.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is rather standard practice for mobile networks to "illegally" use public address space as if it were private. *They **all** do this.*

Comment: It is difficult to know by looking at the address (outside RFC1918) if it really is public or private. Further, knowing what nat domain systems are within is nearly impossible.

Comment: I sat through a T-Mobile demonstration a while back. T-Mobile is interesting in that it is starting to put everything on IPv6. The IPv4 addresses for those devices are not real. T-Mobile came up with a home-grown solution to let IPv6 devices communicate with the IPv4 Internet. I think that something like 60% of the T-Mobile phones are actually IPv6-only, but use the proprietary solution to communicate with IPv4. Your application may need to be re-engineered for that carrier.

Comment: @RickyBeam - do you know if most cellular internet network access points support hairpin translation? Because if they all did I wouldn't have to bother with using local addresses for mobile devices.

Comment: I mean that the IPv4 addresses don't actually exist until you get deeper into the T-Mobile network, well beyond the cell tower. The only real IP addresses that the devices have are IPv6 addresses. You could certainly use the link-local IPv6 addresses to communicate locally. My understanding is that T-Mobile is on a direct path to eliminating real IPv4 on the mobile phone.

Comment: Oh, I understand what you're saying. At the software level, if I ask the T-mobile phone what it's local ip address is, I might get an ipv6 address. My phone is actually an ATT phone unlocked and used on T-mobile's network, so maybe that's why I always get local ipv4 addresses on my phone, never ipv6 ones.

Comment: So if I go to some website that says what my phone's public ip address is, I might get an ipv4 address, but the local address of the device may be ipv6 even if the public ip is ipv4.

Comment: And this might complicate the carrier grade NAT traversal methodologies because one methodology that works on the ATT network and ATT phones might not work on the T-mobile network with T-mobile phones. Oh my this really is frustrating. Thank you for informing me.

Comment: As I understand it, 60% of the phones on T-Mobile are only on IPv6.  Yours may not be one, but don't depend on it remaining that way. Also, someone to whom you wish to connect on the T-Mobile network may not have a real IPv4 address. You could contact T-Mobile for more information on how they work their magic. It would seem that IPv6 could, eventually, simplify your application since you would have a unique link-local address, separate from the global IPv6 address.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't answer your question, but may answer your need:
I fear the only option would be to have all peers register their local IP addresses on a server directly connected to the Internet (without NAT).
Each peer could then query the server for the local and translated IP addresses of others. If their translated public IP addresses are in the same range (allocated in the same AS), they could then try a direct connection through their local IP addresses.

Of course, with end-to-end IPv6 connectivity, there would be no issue...

Comment: "fear the only option would be to have all peers register their local IP address on a server". I am already doing this. Every peer provides a server with its local ip and upon contact with the server, the server stores its public ip. The problem is that when I ask a device (often a laptop) for its local ip address, I sometimes don't get it. Instead I sometimes get a loopback address or I get unnecessary or extraneous addresses for virtual machines on the same device or things of that nature. I need a way to know that the address I requested is actually local.

Comment: Maybe the peers should just provide the server with ALL the addresses for all the network interfaces that are not loopback addresses and the other peer should receive ALL of these addresses and if the public ip's match, and in that case it should try ALL the local addresses just in case the other peer disconnected one of their network interfaces or was using a virtual machine.

Comment: " I need a way to know that the address I requested is actually local": what about looking at the routing table of the device, and take the address associated with the default route ?

Comment: I'm programming in Java for the most part, and java's way of doing it that doesn't work in all cases on all OS's is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481865/getting-the-ip-address-of-the-current-machine-using-java . Your idea might work, but it would require native code. I'm afraid I don't know how to get the default route.

Answer (score 0):

You can't figure out what local address ranges will be used, but you can use the link-local IPv6 addresses to communicate locally in case hairpin translation is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

Proper private addresses are well-known. Occasionally addresses are added to the list but it's rare.

Unfortunately it seems like T-Mobile is using hijacked address space. 21.0.0.0/8 is allocated to "DoD Network Information Center (DNIC)"

Detecting whether a machine is behind a NAT is easy enough, just compare the local IP the client reports for the connection (use the getsockname api call) to the remote IP the server reports for the connection. This will work regardless of whether the local IP addresses used behind the NAT are well-known private IP addresses, hijacked IP addresses or even IP addresses legitimately assigned to the network in question (sometimes it makes sense to use NAT even when your clients have legitimate public IP addresses)

However even if two machines are behind the same public IP there is no guarantee that communicating using their local addresses will work. Equally there is no guarantee that communicating with NAT traversal techniques will work.

So sadly if you want reliable operation you will have to implement a fallback to communicating via your servers.